# Problems with selecting entire text in VS.Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, editor, paragraph, textselection

You may know that when you select your code by default in the VS-Code, the cursor itself selects anything since you stay in the same column of a "code's paragraph". However, this is not the case, some time ago I installed VIM extension and since that moment when I have to select a entire paragraph I have to move the cursor until the end of a line to select that because shortcuts doesn't work to do that.

This is the example of what I'm talking about(I stayed at a code's part but in the same column so I select that with the intention to select the entire paragraph, so this is the result):

[Selection with no **"alt"** shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KR89O.png)

I need help to solve this problem since I've proven the settings of the IDE and even reinstall the extensions, so I'd be so granted for your help, Thx!.

Answer (score 3):

Uncheck:
On the menu bar, Selection -> Column Selection Mode

Comment: This works for me